# Smoke artifacts in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, artifacts

I have a strange issue rendering with Cycles.
These are some rendered images:

[image: burnout]
[image: burnout]

As you can see there is a change in color/light around smoke and expand with smoke.
Based on similar problems I've read, I've tried:

- with different Blender versions
- set "Empty space" to 0 in smoke domain settings
- set "Step Size" to 0.1 in World/Volume settings
- different domain Resolution Divisions
- adaptive vs not adaptive domain

but the result is always the same...
And re-baking the simulation each time is very time consuming.
The only clue so far is this image:

[image: denoising depth]

As you can see the artifacts correspond to denoising depth image, but I cannot relate this to final image since I'm not using denoiser...